# Calcular tempo de ProgressBar circular C# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

Tenho o seguinte ProgressBar circular, a ideia é que ele seja decrementado segundo por segundo, até aí tudo bem.
Porém, preciso que a barra comece sempre completa (circulando o circulo 100%) e o valor vai ser dado pelo usuário, então pode ser 120 minutos, 90 minutos, e por aí vai...Quero fazer com que a barra decremente com o tempo exato que ele levará para chegar em 0 minutos.

Por exemplo, **se o usuário entrar com o valor 26 minutos, a barra tem que levar exatos 26 minutos para chegar no 0.**

Alguma ideia de como fazer esse cálculo exato?

Obs: estou utilizando Timer.

[image: ProgressBar circular]

Comment: O tempo total é `minutos*60` a cada segundo a percentagem completa é  `segundos_decorridos / (minutos*60)`. Se quiser fazer de 100 para 0 é só inverter fazendo `1-percentagem_completa`

Answer (score 1):

Simples, defina o intervalo do `timer` para 1 segundo.

Atribua o valor da `progressBar` como `[minutos escolhido pelo usuário] * 60`

A cada `tick` do `timer`, decrementa um valor da `progressBar`